# Login failed for user sa while accessing DBContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I am getting error: **Cannot open database "MyTestDataBase" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'sa'.'**

I am working with a ***web api application using asp.netcore 2.2 and EF core*** .

using: VS2019, asp.Net core 2.2, EFCore on windows pc.
Sql Server is installed on same pc.

It was working fine earlier before latest visual studio 2019 version. (current version: visual studio 2019 16.1.5)
sa user has permission to access my database and verified same with ssms and odbc connection.

but asp.net core application is throwing such error. I am running in debug mode.

my connection string in appsettings.json

```
"DBContext": "Server=MyServer\\ADVANCE;Database=MyTestDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=False;user id=sa;password=123456;Application Name=MyTestData;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

I have also tried with below connection string and getting same error

```
"DBContext": "Server=MyServer\\ADVANCE;Database=MyTestDataBase;User ID=sa;Password=123456;"
```

Comment: What is the corresponding entry in the SQL Server error log for the login attempt?

Comment: not sure it is the problem, but try removing Integrated Security=SSPI as the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication with that set

Comment: The `sa` account is essentially root. Permissions is not an issue. And, you should also totally not be using it for a web app DB user for that reason as well. Regardless, either the password is bad or there's something wrong with the DB instance, like it's in single-user mode or in a detatched state.

Comment: Sql Server Error Log: Login failed for user 'sa', Reason: Failed to Open the explicitly specified database 'MyTestDatabase' [Client: <local machine>]

Comment: Thanks Alex. K. Your comment helping me to finding the issue. It's database name which is wrong , I had restored a backup which has extra 't' in db name.